# Dynamically resize large image to thumbnail in PHP?

Tags: php

What would be the best way to dynamically resize an image to thumbnail when a user requests a photo?   The images were uploaded already as jpgs that are hi res over 3MB?   I already know the file name from the database of which image they are requesting, example:   photo100.jpg, so creating a thumbnail in the php, then serving that newly created thumbnail t_photo100.jpg as a img src= would be ideal

Comment: I would suggest you store thumbnails as a separate image on your server. You can always set an image width and height via html attributes or css, but that will still result in loading a huge image. 

When you upload images to your website you could use the upload.php class. Documentation can be found here:


http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload_docs.htm.

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look at SimpleImage class here:

http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

I use it and it is pretty good and simple. 
Basically you can just do

```
include('SimpleImage.php');
$image = new SimpleImage();
$image->load('picture.jpg');
$image->resize(250,400);
$image->save('picture2.jpg');
```

You can use this preprocessing once and show new created image.

Comment: This is a dead link now

Comment: https://github.com/rutera/simpleimage/blob/master/Simpleimage.php

Answer (score 3):

There are functions in php to do this. Look at this tutorial to see how to resize images:http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php/

Then direct all your image requests to a php file (using .htaccess) that can find the file requested, pass the original through the resizer, then output the new thumbnail

Answer (score 2):

You can use a library like [PHPThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) for this purpose.

It makes use of ImageMagick (if available) and PHP GD Library (comes with PHP v4.3.0+) for processing the images.

Once it's configured and set up, you can dynamically generate image thumbnails, like so:

```
<img src="/uploads/phpThumb.php?src=images/logo.png&w=100" />

<img src="/uploads/phpThumb.php?src=images/foobar.png&h=50&w=50&zc=1" />
```

Check the [demo page](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/demo/demo/phpThumb.demo.demo.php) for more options.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is this based on the same code as TimThumb? I used to use TimThumb, but have now read that it's unsupported due to the previous security exploits. Does this PHPThumb inherit those at all?

Comment: @Lee: I haven't used PHPThumb much, but I don't think it inherits code from TimThumb. And unlike the other one, this one seems to somewhat maintained - https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/phpThumb

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the easiest way would be to use imagemagick (http://phpsnips.com/snip-111#.UhT5XZJwok0):

```
<?php 
// Location to upload main image: 
$mainDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/l/'; 
// Location to create the thumb image: 
$smalDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/s/'; 
// Command to use: 
$command = '/usr/bin/convert'; 
// Thumbnail width: 
$size = 210; 
// Make sure we have an image: 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 
    if(getimagesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])){ 
        $name = $_FILES['photo']['name']; 
        $uploadfile = $mainDir . $name; 
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile); 
        $lrgImg = $mainDir . $name; 
        $smlImg = $smalDir . $name; 
        $imageMagick = $command . " '". $lrgImg . "' -resize '$size' '" . $smlImg . "'";         
        shell_exec($imageMagick); 
    } 
    header("Location: /test.php"); 
    exit; 
}else{ 
?> 
    <form action=" <?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> " method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p><input type="file" name="photo" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Upload!" name="submit" /></p>
    </form>
<?php 
    foreach(glob($smalDir.'*') as $img){ 
        echo ' <img src="'.str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '',$img).'" /> '; 
    } 
} 
?>
```

You could also do it using PHPGD (http://phpsnips.com/snip-5#.UhT5yJJwok0):

```
<?php 
function createThumbnail($imageDirectory, $imageName, $thumbDirectory, $thumbWidth, $quality){ 
    $details = getimagesize("$imageDirectory/$imageName") or die('Please only upload images.'); 
    $type = preg_replace('@^.+(?<=/)(.+)$@', '$1', $details['mime']); 
    eval('$srcImg = imagecreatefrom'.$type.'("$imageDirectory/$imageName");'); 
    $thumbHeight = $details[1] * ($thumbWidth / $details[0]); 
    $thumbImg = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbWidth, $thumbHeight); 
    imagecopyresampled($thumbImg, $srcImg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $thumbWidth, $thumbHeight,  
    $details[0], $details[1]); 
    eval('image'.$type.'($thumbImg, "$thumbDirectory/$imageName"'. 
    (($type=='jpeg')?', $quality':'').');'); 
    imagedestroy($srcImg); 
    imagedestroy($thumbImg); 
} 

foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) { 
   if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { 
       $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key]; 
       $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key]; 
       move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "data/$name"); 
       createThumbnail("/location/of/main/image", $name, "/location/to/store/thumb", 120, 80); 
       //120 = thumb width  ::  80 = thumb quality (1-100) 
   } 
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Normaly you would use something like this:

```
<img src="/images/uploads/image50.jpg" />
```

Replace that with something like this while generating the html.

```
<img src="image.php?img_url=<?=base_64_encode("/images/uploads/image50.jpg")?>&width=128" />
```

and then use a image.php file like this:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");

$imgUrl = base64_decode($_GET["img_url"]);
$c = file_get_contents($imgUrl);
$arr = getimagesizefromstring($c);

$img = imagecreatefromstring($c);

if (!is_array($arr)) {
    //remote image is not available. Use default one.
    $c = file_get_contents("include/images/nobanner.jpg");
}

if (isset($_GET["width"])){
  //Get Width and Height
  List($Width, $Height) = getimagesize($imgUrl);

   //Calc new Size
  $w = $_GET["width"];
  $h = $Height * ($w / $Width);

  //Build the image
  //Create new Base
  $NewImageBase = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);

  //copy image
  imagecopyresampled($NewImageBase, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $Width, $Height);
  $img = $NewImageBase;
}

imagejpeg($img);
?>
```

However remember, that this will cause a intensive calculation everytime somebody access an image. You could optimize the image.php file, to "save" thumbnails, once they have been created, and simple return that file, if required.

Also this will bypass the browsers image caching, causing more traffic on every page refresh.

Answer (score 1):

From Php.net:

2 main function you might need:

1: **imagecopyresampled**

```
<?php
// The file
$filename = 'test.jpg';

// Set a maximum height and width
$width = 200;
$height = 200;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new dimensions
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);

$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
   $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
} else {
   $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
}

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
?>
```

2: **imagecopyresized**

```
<?php
// File and new size
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$percent = 0.5;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new sizes
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$newwidth = $width * $percent;
$newheight = $height * $percent;

// Load
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth, $newheight);
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Resize
imagecopyresized($thumb, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newwidth, $newheight, $width, $height);

// Output
imagejpeg($thumb);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing similar issue. I searched but couldn't find appropriate solution. So, I created one. This will work with CDN (cloudfront) reducing load on your php webserver. I have run it in production with different device sizes and the results are astounding. Do give it a try: https://github.com/thekosmix/php-image-resizer

How this works: hit the CDN with http://url/width/height/imagename. If it's present in the CDN, it will be served. Else it will hit php server, get resize the original image and store it on CDN and start serving from there for every request.