# How to resize images on the fly in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, image

I have a `php` page that has a lot of images. And depending on the client window size the image size changes. For my specific scenario, I need the image width to be exactly the size of the `div` it's in (like pixel-to-pixel).

So basically, how do I load the different sizes of the image? I cant create all the possible width's of the image beforehand.

Is there a way to do this resizing dynamically?

Comment: See this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18363969/dynamically-resize-large-image-to-thumbnail-in-php#18364047

Comment: @AlokPatel honestly that seems a bit beyond me :(

Comment: It makes little sense to have a different image for each specific pixel width (regardless of whether those images are created dynamically.) You should rather use responsive images.

Comment: I don't think you'd need to resize images that much, as flies are really small so there's not a lot of scope for having large HD image on a little fly..... *groan*

Comment: There are very good reasons to want to do this, especially when you're displaying product images and they're all different sizes.  They won't show up correctly in a magnifier or when shown side by side with other images of different proportions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a server running `php`, you can use one of these libraries to resize the images on the fly:

1. [meenie/munee](https://github.com/meenie/munee)
2. [mos/cimage](https://github.com/mosbth/cimage)

You can install the library using [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) by running `composer require meenie/munee` or `composer require mos/cimage`

Then you can link your photos by using one of these:

1. Meenie: `<img src="/path/to/image.jpg?resize=width[100]">`
2. cImage: `<img src="/host/img.php?src=test.png&width=100">`

Comment: can you explain how I'd do this?

Comment: @JillyDelial hope this explains how to do it.

Comment: could this crash the server the I post the code on?

Comment: @JillyDelial that's a legitimate concern if you have a lots of requests for different sizes (especially if the image sizes get big), but you'll have to decide that on your own. It depends on your image sizes and number of requests.

Comment: @JillyDelial `mos/cimage` also has caching that allows it to caches the image if it was processed once before, so if you're concerned about burdening the server, I'd go with that one instead (I'm not sure about `Meenie/Munee`)

Comment: honestly I've used `composer` couple times and that's it. how hard are these to configure. (I just looked at @AlokPatel suggestion, and that was too beyond me).

Comment: @JillyDelial both `munee` and `cimage` are quite easy to setup, just follow the documentation I linked.

Comment: thank you so much. I made an account just to ask this question.